# How to stream different videos to the same RTMP URL?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, red5, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying to develop a video conferencing application using Red5 as server and Flash and Adobe Air as the client sides. After learning how to create a simple video chat application using Flex,I am confused that how can we stream videos of many people in a conference to the same rtmp url?
**my rtmp url is: rtmp://localhost/MyFirstRed5Server**

Now I am not being able to understand the logic here.I need different URL's for different user or I can stream all of the users' video to the same rtmp url? I am a beginner so please do not mind the ambiguities in my question and also my English. I just need some heads up. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I never had expirience with RED5, but with Adobe FMS rtmp(or rtmfp) url is only needed for connecting NetConnection object. You create streams by using NetStream's publish method giving it a stream name. Other's can play that stream knowing it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

every user will connect to the same rtmp-url.
But when you load the video you connect to another NetStream.

So the NetConnection can be shared accross all NetStreams, but of course every client in the video chat has its own stream.

You just need to make sure that sender and receivers know the name of the stream, probably you send a message over RTMP or via SharedObject about the name of the stream.
You can catch the event when somebody starts to stream on Red5/Server-Side. So there is actual no need for the client to actively create a message and send something upfront. You can just listen for that event on server side and then sync to all clients (except the one that is broadcasting).

Sebastian

Comment: Thank you Sebastian for you answer. I have already used SharedObjects for each client to ask the server for its unique id which will also be the stream name. When a new client joins the conference,server will give it a new id,and send that id to all the connected clients. Is this the correct way to do it? 

One more thing,what should I do for the java based clients? There is no way I can publish or access using the stream names coz I will only be able to access the top level url streams : rtmp://[host]/myserver . Is there any way I can resolve the streams into a rtmp url?

Comment: you can try RTMPClient.java class. But we only use it for publishing, not for receiving streams. I would not make a fixed id for each client, cause a client can publish multiple streams (or re-publish after changing settings). Also you still need to wait on each client until the streaming really started. So I would overwrite the method "streamPublishStart" in the ApplicationAdapter to listen for stream start events, and use that to notify all clients of a new stream. Not just "when a new client joins a room". Cause a new client can join a room, but that does not mean he  broadcasts anything

Comment: Thanx sebastian, you just saved a lot of my time by mentioning these small yet very important informations. I was notifing the clients when the client joined the room and was thinking why the video was not updated... Thanks again. If you know about the flex sdk, do u know how I can make a client's video full screen when it is clicked?

Comment: fullscreen is flash is a bit odd. The problem is that the only button that will work when you are in full screen is the "esc" button (to leave full screen). The reason why is that otherwise somebody could for example put a full screen in front of view that looks like your online banking website, and steal your user/pwd. But however if you still feel it makes sense for you, there are plenty of examples of how to do that in the www ... or start a new thread. Basically you need to add some attribute to the HTML embed code of the SWF and then you can run some as3 snippet to go fullscreen

Comment: But when I try to use multiple FFMPEG processes (on a single server) to stream a video (on the server) to the same URL (on a different server), it gives an error: `[rtmp @ 0x568ba09317c0] Server error: Already publishing
rtmp://<ip address>/mystream: Operation not permitted`. I'm doing it with the objective of load testing.